# How to reduce scan count on table with a composite index?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table (T) with ~3 million rows and just two INT columns (ID1 and ID2), which together are set as a composite clustered key.

Early in a stored procedure we create a table variable (@A) which consists of a list of INTs.

The slow query is the following

```
SELECT T.ID1, T.ID2 
FROM T
INNER JOIN @A AS A 
ON A.ID = T.ID1
```

@A will have just a few hundred rows, and T contains a few million rows. The problem is that T gets a scan count of several hundred. I don't know how to make that go away.

I have tried to create another index on T with column ID1 and ID2 included, but it does not help (the execution planner shows that the new index is used).

What can be done to reduce the scan count on table T?

(We are using SQL Server 2014, Web Edition)

Comment: In what order are the columns in the index?

Comment: The order is ID2, ID1. Will that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating an included (covering index):

```
create index idx_t_id1 on t(id1) include id2
```

This will allow your query to find everything it needs in the index pages and will not have to search in the main table. By the way is there a clustered index on table t?

Comment: That's exactly the index I (poorly) described having tried. The scan count is still in the hundreds. Yes, there is a clustered index on T. The clustered index includes both ID1 + ID2.

Comment: If there are 300 rows in @a you are doing an inner join and if there is one to one matches between @a and t SQL Server will read 300 rows from t. What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like the answer is that I was under an old assumption that scan count means full table scan. I did som googling and realized nowadays it just means table accesses - so the problem does not seam to have been there in the first place. But your index suggestion is clearly what would have been the answer if it was not already there. So I am marking your answer as the correct one. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try phrasing the query like this:

```
select a.id as id1,
       (select t.id2
        from t
        where t.id1 = a.id
       ) as id2
from @a a;
```

This should scan `@a` and use the index for the lookup.

Two notes:

- If there can be multiple matches, use `cross apply` instead.
- If there could be no matches and you want to filter the rows, use a subquery or CTE.

Answer (score 0):

You should try temp table (#table) instead of table var (@table). SQL Server Always estimate @table as 1 row table and this could impact you query performance a lot. Another benefit to use #table is that you can create index on that ;)